# How do we debug java native memory corruption?

Tags: java, heap-corruption, memory-corruption

How do we debug JAVA native memory corruption? See the error below. This is not reproducible.

```
   *** glibc detected *** java: malloc(): memory corruption:  ***
   ======= Backtrace: =========
   /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I have found below bug, but this is not exactly same and already closed
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8014517

Enabled native memory tracking and memory looks fine

Native Memory Tracking:

```
Total: reserved=2602850KB, committed=1328902KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=1048576KB, committed=1048576KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=1048576KB, committed=1048576KB)

-                     Class (reserved=1086404KB, committed=41872KB)
                            (classes #6772)
                            (malloc=964KB #9821)
                            (mmap: reserved=1085440KB, committed=40908KB)

-                    Thread (reserved=97840KB, committed=97840KB)
                            (thread #68)
                            (stack: reserved=97548KB, committed=97548KB)
                            (malloc=214KB #347)
                            (arena=79KB #130)

-                      Code (reserved=253706KB, committed=26338KB)
                            (malloc=4106KB #6430)
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=22232KB)

-                        GC (reserved=96873KB, committed=96873KB)
                            (malloc=25193KB #14649)
                            (mmap: reserved=71680KB, committed=71680KB)

-                  Compiler (reserved=191KB, committed=191KB)
                            (malloc=61KB #338)
                            (arena=131KB #7)

-                  Internal (reserved=5227KB, committed=5227KB)
                            (malloc=5195KB #14491)
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB)

-                    Symbol (reserved=9882KB, committed=9882KB)
                            (malloc=6103KB #51834)
                            (arena=3780KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=1903KB, committed=1903KB)
                            (malloc=302KB #4286)
                            (tracking overhead=1601KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=199KB, committed=199KB)
                            (malloc=199KB)

-                   Unknown (reserved=2048KB, committed=0KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=2048KB, committed=0KB)
```

Comment: What exactly are you running? Any code samples that is causing the corruption or is it on all java applications? If it is; try getting a fresh java installation and reinstalling it.

Comment: There is no application code change, happend this after a fresh java installation

Comment: What version of java are you running?

Comment: using java 1.8.0_231

Comment: Try this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/troubleshoot/troubleshoot-system-crashes.htm#JSTGD314

Comment: @StephenC JVM was not crashed, only this memory corruption error was printed

Comment: Well, be that as it may, you should read that document for ideas on how to debug >>your<< problem.  Also https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E21993/blamm.html

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256176/how-to-debug-java-jni-using-gdb-on-linux or google "java debug jni  gdb"

Comment: Do you have a more detailed stack trace?